# CSS: Click button to transition and keep style open

Tags: html, css

That might sound odd, but essentially, I'm trying to make it so when i click on a designated button/spot on a page, it opens up a CSS border box that contains information. I know how to make it hidden, but like when you hover and it appears using the :hover attribute, i want to make it stay permanently visible after the hover transition is complete. Can this be done with CSS? Or is it going to require Javascript? Here is the code I'm using as a starter base.

```css
#information {
  border: solid 2px #FF8000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 48%;
  width: 24%;
  left: =0.6%;
  top: 0.7%;
  padding: 0.4%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: rgba(114, 70, 0, 0.3);
  overflow: hidden;
}

#information:hover {
  left: 74.6%;
}
```

```html
<div id="information">
  <div style=" height: 325px; overflow-x: hidden;" align="left">
    <i>Information</i>
    <br><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sorry, I'm new to the site, and I'm still working out how to format my posts.

Comment: If you just want what you have here to stay visible after hovering, you have to use javascript. You could make a thing you click on and it will show/hide based on click using just CSS though.

Comment: It cannot be done with CSS alone. You need Javascript. Try JQuery.

Comment: This is for a profile on a roleplaying website that uses HTML and CSS for its profile creation, just a heads up. It has Javascript enabled, however, i don't know Javascript at all, and I'm a little worried about using something I don't know how to edit and manipulate. Is there an easy to understand way to learn how the basics work before i start playing with it then? I've tried to avoid Javascript at all costs because its code makes no sense to me.

Comment: @NawedKhan you don't need to add a massive library to get one simple js hover effect, seems a bit like overkill to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to make it so when i click on a designated button/spot on a page, it opens up a CSS border box that contains information.

You can use the "checkbox hack" to pull off changes like this in CSS. https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/

```css
#information {
  border: solid 2px #FF8000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 48%;
  width: 24%;
  left: =0.6%;
  top: 0.7%;
  padding: 0.4%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: rgba(114, 70, 0, 0.3);
  overflow: hidden;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  left: 74.6%;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="box">
<label id="information" for="box">
  <div style=" height: 325px; overflow-x: hidden;" align="left">
    <i>Information</i>
    <br><br>
  </div>
</label>
```

Comment: `i want to make it stay permanently visible after the hover transition is complete.` he was talking about hover. that ( as far as i know ) can't be done with css alone

Comment: @MihaiT right, they also said what I quoted in the post. They can tell me if it doesn't help, and if it doesn't, I'll delete the post. *"I'm trying to make it so when i click on a designated button/spot on a page, it opens up a CSS border box that contains information."*

Comment: This is actually a tremendous help. It's the closest thing I've been able to find. Thank you! I'll use this for now until i get more experienced. I don't know if i can add a transition effect to this, but it's perfect for what i need till i understand it better. Thank you kind sir!

Comment: @FenixTigerZ you're welcome. this is the closest thing you can get to doing this kind of stuff with CSS. I would recommend learning JS, it's really easy and is the way to do this kind of stuff. You might look at jquery because it has a lot of stuff that does this and it's usually easier to use than JS for beginners. it's just a JS library (someone else's JS they turned into something easy to use)

Comment: @MichaelCoker I'll check it out and see if there's anything helpful there. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

```css
#information {
  border: solid 2px #FF8000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 48%;
  width: 24%;
  left: =0.6%;
  top: 0.7%;
  padding: 0.4%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: rgba(114, 70, 0, 0.3);
  overflow: hidden;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  left: 74.6%;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="box">
<label id="information" for="box">
  <div style=" height: 325px; overflow-x: hidden;" align="left">
    <i>Information</i>
    <br><br>
  </div>
</label>
```

My solution is similar to what @Michael Coker suggested. We can use radio button instead to disable click on label after first click. I removed the inner div inside #information to make HTML W3C valid.